# Mongoose specifying an _id on upsert (Query)

Tags: node.js, mongoose, insert-update, upsert

In my chat application, every user has a dictionary of unread messages which looks like this :

**Unread Dictionary**

```
{
    _id: // reference to their user_id,
    events: [] // array of ObjectIds
}
```

I want to make a mongoose findByIdAndUpdate query where ) search by ID and $push a new ObjectId into the events array.

If the document doesn't exist, I would like for it to upsert the document assigning it the _id used for the update query and initializing the array with the element being $push ed in the update query.

EDIT:

Here is an example of the query I would like to make:

Model.findByIdAndUpdate(user_id, {$push: {events: event_id}}, {upsert: true}, function (err, updatedDoc) {});

If the document doesn't exist and it decides to upsert, will it use the user_id I used to search to assign the _id on the upserted document? OR will mongo assign it's own _id? I'm looking for something that does the former.

Comment: Sounds like a standard upsert, did it not work when you tried it?

Comment: @JohnnyHK I assumed mongoose would assign it's own _id if it was unable to find the document, and upserted it. Is this not true?

Comment: It's probably best if you add some code to your question that better illustrates exactly what you're looking to do.

Comment: I would expect that will do what you're looking for.  Just try it.

Answer (score 1):

The question is too long, but I hope my answer will help someone. We can use **$setOnInsert** to specify field only used on insert:

```
const idUsedOnInsert = new mongoose.Types.ObjectID();

const document = await Model.findByIdAndUpdate(
      user_id,
      { $push: { events: event_id }, $setOnInsert: { _id: idUsedOnInsert } },
      { upsert: true }
    );

if(document){
    console.log('Update');
} else {
    console.log('Insert');
}
```

Comment: I think it would be easier to add the generated _id to the object before running findByIdAndUpdate.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose will use the `_id` you passed as the object `_id` when upserting.

You can try that on your console.

Create an ObjectId: `const id = ObjectId()`, 
then query with `<Model>.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { name: 'Albert' }, { upsert: true })`.

And also, if you want to receive the object when it's upsert, you need to pass `new: true` within the query options, or else you will receive `null` for upserts*

*that's because by default, mongoose/MongoDB returns the `find` query's result instead the `update`'s result, if you'd have queried an update on an existing object, you'd receive the old object in case you didn't pass the `new: true` option.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option